# Why am I not getting any notifications from the Google Drive API?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I believe I have configured everything properly as I am getting the sync message when subscribing but not getting any notifications after that when I upload files.

I have done the following:

- have a working endpoint that simply outputs the request received
- enabled the Google Drive API in the dev console
- endpoint is secured with valid cert
- registered endpoint URL in the Google developer console (added to valid domains)
- created a service account with Owner rights (bad idea I know but wanted to make sure this wasn't a permission issue)
- subscribed using https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes/watch

I got a valid subscribe response and my endpoint got a message after the POST to /watch but no notifications after that of any of the changes I made to the drive (adding or removing files).

Does anyone have any idea why I may not be getting notifications despite having successfully gotten the sync?

Here is the message received by the endpoint. The 'origin' is such because I am using the Insomnia REST client to subscribe.

```
{
"body": {},
"headers": {
    "X-Goog-Resource-ID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "CloudFront-Viewer-Country": "US",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "X-Goog-Channel-Expiration": "Wed, 20 Dec 2017 01:39:47 GMT",
    "CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer": "true",
    "CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer": "false",
    "X-Goog-Resource-URI": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes?includeCorpusRemovals=false&includeRemoved=true&includeTeamDriveItems=false&pageSize=100&pageToken=6&restrictToMyDrive=false&spaces=drive&supportsTeamDrives=false&alt=json",
    "User-Agent": "APIs-Google;(+https://developers.google.com/webmasters/APIs-Google.html)",
    "Host": "services.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com",
    "CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate,br",
    "X-Forwarded-Port": "443",
    "X-Amz-Cf-Id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==",
    "CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer": "false",
    "X-Goog-Resource-State": "sync",
    "Via": "1.1 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)",
    "X-Forwarded-For": "66.102.7.129, 52.46.30.57",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
    "X-Goog-Channel-ID": "test-drive-file-notification",
    "CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer": "false",
    "X-Goog-Message-Number": "1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Also other than the dashboard which just shows activity, are there any sort of logs for the Google API activity?

Comment: Did you setup a webhook as mentioned in [Drive Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push)?

Comment: Thank you for commenting @noogui! Yes, I did. That's the endpoint I was referencing above. 
I figured out what my issue was though. Not a technical one, I just assumed the creating credentials with access to google Drive associated with my account that meant the credentials impersonate my access to the Drive. That turns out to be incorrect. Not even adding the credential's client email to the list of writers to a folder would generate notifications. I had to create a folder with those credentials then add my own account to it to access it. Only then did the notifications start streaming in.

Comment: Good thing you found out. I did notice, since you mentioned 'service account', that you might have wrongly assumed it's your account. In truth service accounts are of their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was based on the erroneous assumption that creating credentials with access to Google Drive while logged in as myself (an account NOT associated with a GSuite org) in the google developer console meant the credentials impersonate my access to the Drive. That turns out to be incorrect.

The solution to getting notifications was to create a folder with those credentials (where the service account is the owner) then add my own account to it to access it. Only then did the notifications start streaming in.